How can I connect to my self-hosted openvpn access server from kde system settings?
I have an .ovpn config that I use daily on my iPhone and Mac using the OpenVPN client apps, and I’m trying to set it up on my Steam Deck (SteamOS which is Arch based) for cloud gaming.
I installed the OpenVPN CLI (I think it was networkmanager-openvpn), and I am able to connect from the terminal. However, connecting via CLI is unintuitive for me since I want to be able to connect using a plugin that enables/disables VPN profiles in system settings.
I imported my profile into settings, filled in the same profile username and password I use on all my devices, and applied it:

This popup appears when I try to connect, saying “Provide the secrets for the VPN connection. A password is required.” Whatever I enter, the popup goes away and comes back after a second without any errors:

I also tried changing the connection type to “Password” (it was “Password with Certificates” after import), but I’m still getting the same popup:

I don’t know what password I need to enter or why it's asking for this. Any help is appreciated.

I solved the issue on server side with gpt's help. I logged into openvpn access server admin panel, went to configuration > advanced vpn. I set "Allowed data channel ciphers" to AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC and restarted the vpn. I am now able to connect without changing anything on the client side. Seems the issue was related to cipher negotiation.
